# Shut-down/Restart/Power-up "work" as Suspend on a Lenovo g50-70 running Ubuntu MATE 15.10

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown, mate

As the title suggests; when it comes to *shut-down/restart* both suspend the laptop unless I go with `sudo -shutdown` which works as expected. When *powering-up*, it goes through the GRUB (since I'm dualbooting), and then the MATE loader appears. Seconds later the laptop is suspended. A mouse-click will then prompt me to the account-password interface, and after entering the password, another suspend. This often happens a third time, but it seems random.

Any thoughts?

*02/02/2016 Update-* So MATE updated today (see below) and on restart the laptop went into suspend 6 times till I reached the desktop. In addition, no wireless networks would show up- this resolved by `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

- (status installed) linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic:amd64 4.2.0-27.32
- linux-image-extra-4.2.0-27-generic:amd64 4.2.0-27.32
- linux-image-generic:amd64 4.2.0.27.30 status
- linux-headers-4.2.0-27:all 4.2.0-27.32
- linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic:amd64 4.2.0-27.32
- linux-headers-generic:amd64 4.2.0.27.30
- linux-generic:amd64 4.2.0.27.30
- linux-signed-image-4.2.0-27-generic:amd64 4.2.0-27.32
- linux-signed-image-generic:amd64 4.2.0.27.30
- linux-signed-generic:amd64 4.2.0.27.30
- linux-libc-dev:amd64 4.2.0-27.32

*03/02/16*- Haven't applied any changes since last update. Third power-up attempt and what seems to be random now is actually booting (took ~30mins of *-loading-suspend-"lit" black screen-* loops). I pressed the power-off button while stuck in a black screen and for a while some commands appeared including something about **ascii [OK]** and **failing to start login service** (didn't have enough time to note more than that before getting into another black screen). The web connectivity also drops from time to time, while my other devices have proper access.

Ideas? :)